# Only objectID is saved in the array in another model in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models in my mongoDB. One is `user` model and one is `event` model. What I want to achieve is, when I will add a new event then, that **event array** will save to my **user model's events** column array. Till now, I've successfully saved that **id** of that event to specific `user but the problem is only the **objectID** is coming not the property is showing up like`event name`,`descriptions`. This is my code:

**user model:**

```
const userSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    events: [
        { 
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'Event' 
        }
    ]
});
```

**Event model:**

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
    creator: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    ename: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
});
```

**routes.js**

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

  const event = new Event();
  event.creator = '5d9e1ba694f44227e1f54cc0',
  event.ename = req.body.ename;

  event.save( (err, result) => {
      if (!err)
          res.redirect('events');
      else {
          console.log('error', err);
      }
  }); 
  User.findOneAndUpdate('5d9e1ba694f44227e1f54cc0', {$push: { events: [event] }}, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          console.log('event is saved');
      }
  });

});
```

for simplicity, I've kept my user id hardcoded. Now, how can I update the `$push` method of the mongodb so that the whole properties of the event is to save in the `user` model not only the objectID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be getting a little confused with how you have set up your model & how mongoose [Query Population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) works.

In `userSchema`, you have defined that `events` is an array of type [Schema.Types.ObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) and each 'Event' references a document in the `eventSchema` schema. Because of this, you cant expect `events` to be an array of `Event`.

However, because you have defined this reference in your schema when you query for a document, you can use the [Model.Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method.

```
const user = await findById("id").populate("events");
```

This method will find a `User` and for each `Event` will look up the `Event` collection to find a relating document with that ObjectID. This will return a `User` with the `events` array being populated with the corresponding `Event`

Comment: i tried your code but got this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "Event"` while using `.populate("events")`

Comment: even if i use `.populate("event")`, then objectID is not even inserted

Comment: Could you try, `populate("Event")` and also, make sure you are only saving _ids to the `events` array? I assume your using promises instead of the callback in your snippet.

Comment: i'm using your command asyn await in my snippet now. And did try `.populate("Event")` but no luck

Comment: are you querying for a valid ID? `await Model.findById("A-VALID-ID").populate("events");`

Comment: yes that's valid id, when i print it i saw that `events` array as null

Comment: `{$push: { events: [event] }}` your pushing an object into the schema, it needs to be an _id `{$push: { events: ["EVENT_ID"] }}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200650/discussion-between-insane-da-and-danstarns).